# Why is the explicitly defaulted default constructor implicitly deleted when there is a const std::vector data member?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, clang++, default-constructor

I've got a code really similar to the snippet below:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct dummy
{
    std::vector<int> const data;
    dummy() = default;
};
```

Most compilers accept this code without a glitch except `clang` for versions 9 to 14 that says:

> warning: explicitly defaulted default constructor is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
> note: default constructor of 'dummy' is implicitly deleted because field 'data' of const-qualified type 'const std::vector' would not be initialized

In `clang 15` the issue disappears again.
[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/cvadohfe7)

NB if `const` is removed, the error disappears also.

Yet I would have expect `data` to be initialized to a `const` empty vector.

Is this a `clang` bug? Otherwise, why is this code rejected (and why other compilers do not complain)?

Comment: fwiw, I didnt check the default standard of the different clang versions but even `--std=c++20` for all of them does not change the results https://godbolt.org/z/W9888c3M4

Comment: icx 2022.1.0 gives the same error while 2022.2.0 approves. Smells like a bug in an earlier clang++ version

Comment: @TedLyngmo Likely not a bug, the rules on what can and cannot be `const` default-initialized have changed multiple times (including via DRs). I'll try to get it together for an answer later (if noone is faster).

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, cool.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Try to actually use the constructor. The same version will fail to compile it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Apparently, clang 8 to 15 is C++14. 16 and beyond is C++17. I didn't check older versions.

Comment: @user17732522 My bad, it actually rejects valid code.

Comment: clang bug https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33039 The C++ standard version is irrelevant. The code is valid in any version.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI See my answer.

Comment: In case you're not aware, C++ core guidelines recommend not making members const: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-constref. Usually better to express constness by labelling an object of the type const.

Comment: @TooTone the actual use case is for a non-copyable, non movable, non assignable class :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before resolution of [CWG 2394](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2394.html) a defaulted default constructor was defined as deleted, if any `const` non-static member of class type without a default initializer did not have a user-provided default constructor.

The intention of this rule is to avoid the situation that you default-initialize the object to an indeterminate state that then can't possibly be modified to any usable state, which can only be wrong.

However, the condition isn't quite achieving that and the DR resolves it by making the same requirement as of `const` variable declarations instead, which, after resolution of NB comment RU1 in [P0490](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0490r0.html), correctly consider that even a non-user-provided default constructor may correctly initialize.

Now the issue is that libstdc++ implements the default constructor of `std::vector` by defaulting it (see e.g. [github mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L531C8-L531C26)). The result is that the default constructor is *not* user-provided.

This seems to be a valid implementation, even before the CWG issue or NB comment resolution, because the container requirements are stated only in expressions and declarations that need to be well-formed and it doesn't seem to include any `const` default initialization as far as I can tell.

So it will fail in Clang versions which don't yet implement the defect report and when using libstdc++.

I haven't checked, but the older versions of Clang are probably using older libstdc++ versions where the default constructor is not yet implemented this way. (see [GCC commit e6cad9872b098f50aefb39019b6b1ba74d8c6c07](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/e6cad9872b098f50aefb39019b6b1ba74d8c6c07) from 2018)